# Jquery use css-selectors on retrieved data

Tags: jquery

when I use

```
$.ajax("...", { success: function(data) { /* Do something with data */ }});
```

Is it possible to work on data with css-selectors like `$("body")`? To get only the content of the data's body html tag?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question you are trying to get body from response data.

```
$(data).find("body");
```

example to show content of data - body

```
$.ajax("...", { 
    success: function(data) { 
        /* Do something with data */ 
        alert( $(data).find("body").html()); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: I don't have content of data to try it, but it should work :)

Comment: No, read my answer or [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) : some elements are filtered out when doing `$(htmlpage)`. `$(data)` is already the body content.

Comment: You are trying to set data to body? something like this $("body").html(data);

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to load in a div a fragment of the received data, you may use this :

```
$('#result').load('test.html body');
```

See reference of the load function : http://api.jquery.com/load/

If your goal is more general, and you need the body, you may do this :

```
$.ajax("...", { success: function(data) {
    var $body = $(data); // yes, other elements are filtered out
    var bodyHtml = $body.html();
    ...
}});
```

If you want to get another part than the body, you may use a selector :

```
$.ajax("...", { success: function(data) {
    var $element = $(data).find('#myId'); // here finds the element with id myId
    ...
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in ajax method:

```
success:function(data){
    $("#result").text(data.d);
}
```